# MVC3 .valid() is always true

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I am having some problems with the JQuery .valid() method call on an element. I have the following code. Anyone managed this with ASP.net MVC and unobtrusive javascript?

Javascript code

```
$(function() {
    $('#anchor').click(function () {
        if ($('#myform').valid()) {
            alert("it's valid");     
        } 
    });
});
```

HTML view output

```
<div class="editor-label">
    <label for="FirstName">First name</label>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The First name field is required." id="FirstName" name="FirstName" type="text" value="" />
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="FirstName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
```

I have tried all sorts but can not see any problem. The form itself is validating correctly when the submit button is hit.

Comment: you may have not included the jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the valid plugin ( http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid ) you must use validate on the form.

```
$("#myform").validate();
$("a.check").click(function() {
     alert("Valid: " + $("#myform").valid());
     return false;
});
```

Comment: It's still returning true, with the following code $(function () {
    $("#myform").validate();
    $("#anchor").click(function () {
        alert("Valid: " + $("#myform").valid());
        return false;
    });
});